# Error :crash my app -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

I have create a quizapp. But create a some problem , my problem is that myarray is completed after crash my app.

I want to myarray is completed after open UIAlertView.  How it possible please help. Thankyou

```
// int _currentTitle;
// _currentTitle=0;
// NSArray* myarray;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

myarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Jill Valentine", @"Peter Griffin", @"Meg Griffin", nil];
  }


- (IBAction)changeque:(id)sender {
[self changequestion];
}

-(void)changequestion
{
NSString *str = myarray[_currentTitle++];
questionLabel.text = str;


//        if (_currentTitle == myarray.count) { //reload myarray 
//            _currentTitle = 0;
//        }

}
```

Comment: your ques is not clear, `myarray` is only accessible elements 0 to 2.

Comment: _currentTitle = 0 put this line in viewdidload() and check changequestion _currentTitle index not greater then yourarray.count

Comment: @vaibhav i want to myarray counting is end after show alertview, how it possible. Please help

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I putted in viewdidload() but changequestion method please explane some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of conditional to check whether **_currentTitle** is equal to **[myarray count]**. When this condition is met call a method that presents an alert view.

example could be -

```
-(void)changequestion
{

     if (_currentTitle >= [myarray count]) {
          // call method to present alert view
          [self noMoreQuestions];     
     }
     else {
     NSString *str = myarray[_currentTitle];
     questionLabel.text = str;
     }
     _currentTitle++; // this is done last so question at index 0 happens
}

-(void)noMoreQuestions {
     // present alert to user
     UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Your array count has finished" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

     UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction  actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                   }];

     UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                   }];

     [alert addAction:ok];
     [alert addAction:cancel];
     [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
     // remember to reset _currentTitle to 0 before starting next quiz
}
```

Comment: I used your code but second time call changequestion method and direct move to last object. but i want to one bye one count objects and finally open alerview

Comment: I suggest logging the value of _currentTitle at the start of the changequestion method. It should output 0..1..2..3 as each time it is called. Make sure myarray[_currentTitle] is as above and not incremented like in your code. It seems like _currentTitle is being incremented somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry again i used your code and resolve my problem, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

put this:

```
-(void)changequestion
{
if (_currentTitle == myarray.count) { //reload myarray 
         _currentTitle = 0;
     }
NSString *str = myarray[_currentTitle++];
questionLabel.text = str;

}
```

Comment: I want to myarray is completed after open alertview not a repeat myarray

Comment: @DivankKumawat - why is this answer is not useful, where u struck

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for give your precious time. :) My problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

**myarray** has 3 elements, spanning form

> myarray[0] = "Jill Valentine"

,

> myarray[1] = "Peter Griffin"

and

> myarray[2] = "Meg Griffin"

In Obj-C you terminate arrays with a nil value, thus myarray[3] doesn't contain any value. However, your code doesn't show when _currentTitle gets to that value.